# Set Custom Calendar to have Monday as first day of the week

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried to find a solution to have my code for the PoPup Calendar show Monday as the starting week in my buttons. But no matter what I try, the first button is always for a Sunday, as the American way. But as I'm from Sweden I would like to have Monday as the first day of the week..

Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim ThisDay As Date
Dim ThisYear, ThisMth As Date
Dim CreateCal As Boolean
Dim i As Integer

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Application.EnableEvents = False
'starts the form on todays date
ThisDay = Date
ThisMth = Format(ThisDay, "mm")
ThisYear = Format(ThisDay, "yyyy")
For i = 1 To 12
    CB_Mth.AddItem Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + i, 0), "mmmm")
Next
CB_Mth.ListIndex = Format(Date, "mm") - Format(Date, "mm")
For i = -20 To 50
    If i = 1 Then CB_Yr.AddItem Format((ThisDay), "yyyy") Else CB_Yr.AddItem _
        Format((DateAdd("yyyy", (i - 1), ThisDay)), "yyyy")
Next
CB_Yr.ListIndex = 21
'Builds the calendar with todays date
CalendarFrm.Width = CalendarFrm.Width
CreateCal = True
Call Build_Calendar
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub


Private Sub CB_Mth_Change()
'rebuilds the calendar when the month is changed by the user
Build_Calendar
End Sub

Private Sub CB_Yr_Change()
'rebuilds the calendar when the year is changed by the user
Build_Calendar
End Sub


Private Sub Build_Calendar()
'the routine that actually builds the calendar each time
If CreateCal = True Then
CalendarFrm.Caption = " " & CB_Mth.Value & " " & CB_Yr.Value

'sets the focus for the todays date button
CommandButton1.SetFocus
For i = 1 To 43
    If i < Weekday((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value)) Then
        Controls("D" & (i)).Caption = Format(DateAdd("d", (i - Weekday((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value))), _
            ((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value))), "d")
        Controls("D" & (i)).ControlTipText = Format(DateAdd("d", (i - Weekday((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value))), _
            ((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value))), "m/d/yy")
    ElseIf i >= Weekday((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value)) Then
        Controls("D" & (i)).Caption = Format(DateAdd("d", (i - Weekday((CB_Mth.Value) _
            & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value))), ((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value))), "d")
        Controls("D" & (i)).ControlTipText = Format(DateAdd("d", (i - Weekday((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value))), _
            ((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value))), "m/d/yy")
    End If
    If Format(DateAdd("d", (i - Weekday((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value))), _
    ((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value))), "mmmm") = ((CB_Mth.Value)) Then
        If Controls("D" & (i)).BackColor <> &H80000016 Then Controls("D" & (i)).BackColor = &H80000018  '&H80000010
        Controls("D" & (i)).Font.Bold = True
    If Format(DateAdd("d", (i - Weekday((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value))), _
        ((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value))), "m/d/yy") = Format(ThisDay, "m/d/yy") Then Controls("D" & (i)).SetFocus
    Else
        If Controls("D" & (i)).BackColor <> &H80000016 Then Controls("D" & (i)).BackColor = &H8000000F
        Controls("D" & (i)).Font.Bold = False
    End If
Next
End If
End Sub


Private Sub D1_Click()
'this sub and the ones following represent the buttons for days on the form
'retrieves the current value of the individual controltiptext and
'places it in the active cell
ActiveCell.Value = D1.ControlTipText
Unload Me
'after unload you can call a different userform to continue data entry
'uncomment this line and add a userform named UserForm2
'Userform2.Show
'This is multiplied for all 43 buttons with Sub D2, Sub D3 and so on.

End Sub
```

Without giving me the straight answer, could someone help me to point out where is the code the formatting is done? I mean, where is it said that Sunday is the first day of the week?
Or is it default in excel? (My calendar in Outlook and Windows settings are set to English (UK) format.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: WEEKDAY has a 2nd argument for this

Comment: Should i add 
     Weekday((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value), vbMonday))
for all the Weekdays?

Comment: I might be missing something, but wont all Mondays be the same colour so no need for code formatting, just all Mondays are red/bold and just hidden when not used?

Comment: Didn't think you wanted the straight answer :) this should help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82yfs2zh(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: This `dateadd("d",date,1-weekday(date(),vbMonday))` gives the Monday in the current week for example.

Comment: This is the exact code that I got with a sample of it in a ZIP file: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=543.
The problem is not with the color, just the way the Calendar Control works.. I tried to find a way to add a picture in here but doesn't seem to be possible..
I need the form that I have to display the D1 as Monday, D2 as Tuesday and so forth. Right now, D1 becomes Sunday.. Which I do not want. But I admit, this was more complicated than i though :)

Comment: I'd look at using the logic, ` from Weekday(dateserial(year(date),month(date),1),vbMonday) to end of month...` with `1 to Weekday(dateserial(year(date),month(date),1),vbMonday)` being not visible.  I'll do an example

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, using 2 weeks in example, so 14 command buttons, commandbutton1 being a Monday, and using the following code

```
Dim intBtn As Integer
Dim intDay As Integer

intDay = 1

For intBtn = Weekday(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1), vbMonday) To 14
    Me.Controls("CommandButton" & intBtn).Caption = intDay
    intDay = intDay + 1
Next intBtn
```

[image]